# QProcess is not get quit when running windows batch file

Tags: c++, windows, qt, visual-c++

I am running a Windows batch file with the following contents:

```
 @echo off
 :loop
 taskkill /im "app.exe" /fi "STATUS eq NOT RESPONDING" /f >nul && start "" "C:\Program Files\app\app.exe"
 goto loop
```

This will start my application when it is not responding. I run this batch file using a QT application with the following code:

```
  QProcess *process= new QProcess(this);
  process->start("cmd.exe", QStringList() << "/c"<<"C:/Users/test.bat");
```

I kill the process using `process->kill()` in the Qt application's `close` event. But the process doesn't close, it continuously runs the batch file. Is there some other way to kill the process properly?

## app_window.cpp

```
ApplicationWindow::ApplicationWindow( QWidget* inParent ) :
QMainWindow( inParent ),
ui( new Ui::ApplicationWindow )
{
process= new QProcess(this);
process->start("cmd.exe", QStringList() << "/c"<<"C:/Users/test.bat");  
//bat file will monitor this application, when it's not responding, it starts again         
}

void ApplicationWindow::closeEvent( QCloseEvent * inCloseEvent )
{
   process->kill(); // if it killed the batch file, it starts app again
}
```

Comment: Show more source code. Add four spaces before each source code lines to format them properly. So **edit your question** to improve it.

Comment: May be it's bad idea to start process like that if you want it to monitor parent process state. May be `bool QProcess::startDetached()` is a better solution. And if bat-file sees that calling app is not running now, it ends  execution itself.

Comment: Not sure how `cmd.exe /c` behaves, does it actually continue running until the batch file finished? You can check with `QProcess::state` before trying the `kill`.